# Firefox use desktop as mobile browser

Tags: firefox

In firefox mobile for android there is an option called *"request desktop site"*.
I want to know if there is the oposite for desktop, to request the site like a mobile browser.

I know that in the developer panel there is a "responsive design mode", but it only adapts the screen size, it does not request the site as a mobile phone (different from the "request desktop site", that in fact request the desktop version using a desctop user agent name)

Comment: You can probably try to use an extension that forces a different user agent, for example [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/?src=search), and pick a mobile user agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments of my question, the answer was given so I will post it as such(thanks to @Dexter).

For changing the site requested, the user agent must be changed (because the user agent is what pages use to identify weather the client is on desktop or on mobile). An extension like **User Agent Switcher** can do the job.

1. Install the extension from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/?src=search)
2. Select the wanted user agent in the extension menu
3. reload the page